# how to apply setstate in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm making bottomNavigationBar and I want to make theirs buttons changed color when it's clicked. So I made a state that is 'currentTab' and I used it in each buttons's setState(). but It's not working and there's no specific error. Could you review my code below?

```
    
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<BottomBar> createState() => BottomBarState();
}

class BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar>  {

 int currentTab = 0;

 PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
 Widget currentScreen = HomePage();
 final List<Widget> screens = [
   HomePage(),
   ShopPage(),
   PeoplePage(),
   NftPage()
 ];


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return BottomAppBar(
         shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
         notchMargin: 10,
         child: Container(
           height: 60,
           child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
             children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: [
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       setState(() {
                         currentScreen = HomePage();
                         currentTab = 0;

                       });
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  HomePage())
                       );
                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.home,
                           color: currentTab == 0? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       setState(() {
                         currentScreen = ShopPage();
                         currentTab = 1;

                       });
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ShopPage())
                       );

                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,
                           color: currentTab == 1? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,

                         ),

                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               //Right Tab Bar Icons
               Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: [
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       setState(() {
                         currentScreen = NftPage();
                         currentTab = 2;

                       });
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const NftPage())
                       );
                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.account_balance_wallet,
                           color: currentTab == 2? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       setState(() {
                         currentScreen = PeoplePage();
                         currentTab = 3;

                       });
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  PeoplePage())
                       );
                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.people,
                           color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                         ),

                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
     );
 }
}
```

In Rows, there are MaterialButtons and I applied setstate in there.

Answer (score 0):

Because when it try to rebuild view you navigate to other screen, try this:

```
onPressed: (){
   setState(() {
     currentScreen = PeoplePage();
     currentTab = 3;

   });
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.push(
           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  PeoplePage())
        ); 
   }); 
   
 },
```

do this in all yours `onPressed`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using setState in the onPressed of the MaterialButton.

You should use setState in the build method of the widget.

For example:

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<BottomBar> createState() => BottomBarState();
}

class BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar>  {

 int currentTab = 0;

 PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
 Widget currentScreen = HomePage();
 final List<Widget> screens = [
   HomePage(),
   ShopPage(),
   PeoplePage(),
   NftPage()
 ];


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return BottomAppBar(
         shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
         notchMargin: 10,
         child: Container(
           height: 60,
           child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
             children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: [
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  HomePage())
                       );
                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.home,
                           color: currentTab == 0? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ShopPage())
                       );

                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,
                           color: currentTab == 1? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,

                         ),

                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               //Right Tab Bar Icons
               Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: [
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const NftPage())
                       );
                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.account_balance_wallet,
                           color: currentTab == 2? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                   MaterialButton(
                     minWidth: 40,
                     onPressed: (){
                       Navigator.push(
                           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  PeoplePage())
                       );
                     },
                     child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                         Icon(
                           Icons.people,
                           color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                         ),

                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
     );
 }
}
```

In Rows, there are MaterialButtons and I applied setstate in there.